# Find all primes $p$, $q$ such that $pq|(5^p - 2^p)(5^q - 2^q)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

> Find all the primes $p$, $q$ such that $pq|(5^p - 2^p)(5^q - 2^q)$.

I don't know how to start this problem, should I start from format theorem, Please explain the process and idea so that I can to it later .Thanks.

Comment: Then what to do>

Comment: Note that $5^p-2^p=3(5^{p-1}+2\cdot5^{p-2}+\cdots+2^{p-1})$ and similarly for $5^q-2^q$

Comment: L.H.S. much larger than R.H.S.

Comment: Did you type the condition incorrectly?  Do you want to instead ask for $p,q$ s.t. $pq\mid (5^p-2^q)(5^q-2^q)$?  It is clear that $5^n-2^n>3n$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool      yeah you are right , it's my mistake

Comment: The answers for the corrected problem are $p=q=3$ or $\{p,q\}=\{3,13\}$.  My hint is: use Fermat's little thm to show that the case with $p \nmid 5^p-2^p$, $p\mid 5^q-2^q$, $q\mid 5^p-2^p$, and $q\nmid 5^q-2^q$ does not occur.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool thanks you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to rule out $p,q$ being $2$ or $5$ beforehand.

Suppose $p$ divides $5^p-2^p$. By Fermat's little theorem, $5^p-2^p\equiv5-2\equiv3\bmod p$, so $p=3$. We are left with $q\mid117(5^q-2^q)$; $117=3^2\cdot13$ so either $q=3$ (by a symmetric argument as for $p$) or $q=13$, and we have solutions $(p,q)=(3,3),(3,13),(13,3)$.

Now suppose $p\mid5^q-2^q$ and vice versa but $p\nmid5^p-2^p$ and vice versa. Since $5^q\equiv2^q\bmod p$ and (from Fermat's little theorem) $5^{p-1}\equiv2^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p$, we must have $5^{\gcd(q,p-1)}\equiv2^{\gcd(q,p-1)}\bmod p$ and vice versa (swap $p$ and $q$).

$\gcd(q,p-1)=1$ forces $p=q=3$, which we already found, so we now check $\gcd(q,p-1)>1$, which (since $p,q$ are prime) implies $q\mid p-1$ and $p\mid q-1$ and thus $q\le p-1\le q-2$, a contradiction.

Hence the only solutions are $(p,q)=(3,3),(3,13),(13,3)$.

---

*(Answer for original question:)*

We follow the hint given in comments. Note that $5^x-2^x$ can never be $1$. It is $0$ for $x=0$ and $3$ multiplied by a positive integer for $x>0$:
$$5^x-2^x=(5-2)\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}5^{x-1-k}2^k$$
In particular, it is composite if $x>1$.

If one of the two factors was $pq$ the other would have to be $1$, so $5^p-2^p=p$ and $5^q-2^q=q$ or the other way round. Since $p,q\ge2$, both factors $5^x-2^x$ would have to be composite, but they are stipulated to be equal to prime numbers, so no solution exists.

Comment: Sorry , I have a typing mistake . Thanks for sharing your idea .

Comment: @Crevious OK. I now have the correct problem solved.